# mysql, Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql

When I query with:

```
SELECT * FROM database.table LIMIT 0, 100
```

it works fine.

But when I try:

```
SELECT * FROM database.table where date='2016-12-01' LIMIT 0, 100
```

then it will give me an error:

Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

I understand there are a couple of other such threads around and I have tried the suggested solutions including changing connect_timeout to an very large value. Unfortunately, it did not work out for me.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your connection time-outs are.  But, your query is probably doing a full table scan to find the appropriate rows.  An index would really help the query:

```
create index idx_table_date on `table`(date);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. When I tried to do that, I got the same error. Is there any ways to get around it? Here are some of the timeout parameters: connect_timeout=1000, net_read_timeout=600, net_write_time_out=600, wait_timeout=28800, interactive_timeout=28800.

Comment: @BoQiang . . . That really surprises me with the index.

Comment: Yeah...very strange to me. It is like get my hands tied and could not do anything to it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if this is related. This happened since I added two new 'boolean' columns.

Comment: @BoQiang . . . It seems like you should be able to create an index.  Perhaps you need to talk to your DBA.